# Get message to persist in RabbitMQ when there a no consumers

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

My scenario: I want my app to publish logs to RabbitMQ and have another process consume those logs and write to a DB.  Additionally, logs should persist in RabbitMQ even if there is no consumer at the moment.  However, with the code I have now, my logs don't show up in RabbitMQ unless I start a consumer.  What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
var amqp = require('amqp');
var connection = amqp.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5672
});

connection.on('ready', function() {
    // Immediately publish
    setTimeout(function() {
        connection.publish('logs',
            new Buffer('hello world'), {},
            function(err, res) {
                console.log(err, '|', res);
            });
    }, 0);

    // Wait a second to subscribe
    setTimeout(function() {
        connection.queue('logs', function(q) {
            q.subscribe(function(message) {
                console.log(message.data);
            });
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many times the general set up with rabbit MQ is for the publisher to declare and exchange and publish to it.  Then the consumer declares the same exchange (which will just ensure it exists if it is already there and  create it if the consumer starts first).  This is incorrect for your usage.  You need to have the queue created from the moment that you start publishing to it.

The publisher must create the exchange and the queue, the queue needs to be

> autodelete=false

, durable only helps if you plan to restart your RabbitMQ server.  It then publishes to the exchange and the messages will be delivered to the queue where they will wait for your consumer to connect to it and then read all the messages that it missed.  It must use the exact same queue declare parameters as the producer did when it declared the queue.  As it is

> autodelete=false

It will ensure that no matter when the the consumer comes up and down it will stay alive and retain the messages.

Comment: Tested and works!  A little out of scope, but if I wrap my publishes with a Queue declaration, will this incur another round trip to RabbitMQ or will my library (amqp for nodejs) be smart enough to cache which queues it's already created, within a given session?

Comment: If you are using a fixed queue name you only need to create it once.  you could even create it manually externally to your code, if it was completely static.  If you try to create a queue that already exists it will just confirm its existence.